# How do I find the coordinate relationship between numbers on a number spiral?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory

For instance, considering the number spiral below, If I wanted to say where the number $10$ was in relation to the number $18$, I might say something like relationship $(18,10) = (4,-2)$ since it is $4$ places to the right and two places down.

[image]

Is there a general formula for this or a relatively simple algorithm to compute this relationship for any two positive integers on the spiral?

Comment: First you can do everything in relation with $1$ and after that in order to obtain the general formula of Coordinates $(p,q)$ you need to do only to sum the first ones in this way:  Coordinates $(p,q)$= Coordinates $(1,p)$+ Coordinates $(1,q)$

Answer (score 2):

First we need to determine which cycle (distance from center) and sector (north, east, south or west) we are in. Then we can determine the exact position of the number.

The first numbers in each cycle is as follows: `2, 10, 26`

This is a quadratic sequence: `first(n) = (2n-1)^2 + 1 = 4n^2 - 4n + 1 + 1`

The inverse of this is the cycle-number: `cycle(i) = floor((sqrt(i-1) + 1) / 2)`

The length of a cycle is: `length(n) = first(n+1) - first(n) = 8n`

The sector will then be:
`sector(i) = floor(4 * (i - first(cycle(i))) / length(cycle(i)))`

Finally, to get the position, we need to extrapolate from the position of the first number in the cycle and sector.

*Reference + A program written in C language : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550153/determine-position-of-number-in-a-grid-of-numbers-centered-around-0-and-increasi)*

Comment: you must change the formulas a little because they don't have the same spiral

Comment: @Elaqqad It's OK now.